# Reuse SPD list workflow in different environments?

Tags: designer-workflow

I am using SP2013. I have created a workflow on my development environment in SharePoint Designer. I would like to reuse this workflow on my test, acceptance and production environments. What is the best practice to this? Otherwise I need to do everything again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reusable workflows, if possible. So you can use Workflow import/Export feature to use it on different environments. Other way would be package your workflow in a solution.

Also refer:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wkng/archive/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231580.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SP2013 designer workflow then you have the option to **Save the List workflow as template**(note only if the Workflow platform is 2013). This will create a sandbox WSP file in your Site gallery. You can download this WSP file and then upload it in your Test/Acceptance and other servers. Once you deploy that sandbox solution in other server, go to Site Features and a new feature will be seen which title "Workflow template "templateName" from web template "SourceSiteName". Activate this feature and the workflow will be attached to the list.

**Note: Make sure that same list with name is present in the site before activating this feature.**

Comment: And what about the columns in this lists? If the column names are the same, but the id not, is it working ok?

Comment: @KHA the list name should be same and column name also same.. i have not tried by changing the column ids.